# Eliminating extra calls in linked lists

Tags: c++, linked-list

I'm currently implementing a linked list (in my time off!) and am finding that I have functions with structures like this:

```
void traverseList(node *head){
if(head != 0){
    while(head->next !=0){
        cout << head->data << endl;
        head = head->next;
    }

    //one extra for the node at the end
    cout << head->data << endl;
}
}
```

I was wondering in anyone knew of a way to eliminate the 'one extra' calls?

Comment: What on earth is that `new node` doing there?

Comment: @Tom As Mike noticed, why are you creating a new node object here? You're unnecessary creating a memory leak.

Comment: You're correct - I don't need that.

Answer (score 5):

Your function can be greatly simplified to:

```
void traverseList(node *head)
{
    for(node * iterator = head; iterator; iterator = iterator->next)
    {
        cout << iterator->data << endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Change this:

```
if(iterator != 0){
    while(iterator->next !=0){
        cout << iterator->data << endl;
        iterator = iterator->next;
    }

    //one extra for the node at the end
    cout << iterator->data << endl;
}
```

to this:

```
while(iterator != 0) {
    cout << iterator->data << endl;
    iterator = iterator->next;
}
```